# Location for linux libraries without sudo?

Tags: linux, libraries, scientific-linux

I'm at a shared terminal and I want to build a program that works fine on my home computer. I don't have sudo permissions. I need to build a couple of libraries: GotoBlas and UMFpack.

Is there some kind of traditional Linux library location that I can use such as home/lib/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one that will "just work", however you can specify additional lib paths when linking, by using the `-rpath-link` and  `-rpath` options in `ld`.

```
-rpath PATH                 Set runtime shared library search path
-rpath-link PATH            Set link time shared library search path
```

So you can make it whatever will work on your two machines.

Comment: Rather sad. I wonder what people who use shared normally do?

Comment: In a shared environment where you have this level of access there is likely a standard for locally created libraries already in place 
(defined by the creaters of the shared environment).  However, your home machine is entirely separate and so won't conform to this standard.  If you can find out what the standard is, then you can reproduce it.